# Sonar ce start failed , "Address already in use (Bind failed)"

Tags: sonarqube, bind, windows-ce

When I restart sonarqube-7.2, I got this error. I know what the meaning of it is, but I can not find out which port was used.

> 2021.07.27 09:57:38 ERROR ce[][o.s.ce.app.CeServer] Compute Engine startup failed
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not start local HTTP server for System Info monitoring
>
> at org.sonar.ce.httpd.CeHttpServer.start(CeHttpServer.java:70)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110)
> at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89)
> at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84)
> at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169)
> at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132)
> at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110)
> at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1016)
> at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1009)
> at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:767)
> at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
> at org.sonar.ce.container.ComputeEngineContainerImpl.start(ComputeEngineContainerImpl.java:217)
> at org.sonar.ce.ComputeEngineImpl.startup(ComputeEngineImpl.java:45)
> at org.sonar.ce.app.CeServer$CeMainThread.startup(CeServer.java:167)
> at org.sonar.ce.app.CeServer$CeMainThread.attemptStartup(CeServer.java:154)
> at org.sonar.ce.app.CeServer$CeMainThread.run(CeServer.java:141)
>
> Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
>
> at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
> at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
> at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
> at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:329)
> at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$ServerRunnable.run(NanoHTTPD.java:1687)

Comment: Did you try using netstat to find the port sonar is running before restarting it?

Answer (score 1):

In the `conf/sonar.properties` configuration file is a section to configure the web server. See documenation at https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup/install-server/ Default port out of the box should be 9000.